# supertest headers not working on node 16 but working on node 14

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, supertest, nock

I have the following dependency versions

supertest: 6.2.4
nock: 13.2.9
express: 4.17.1
nock: 13.2.9

Now this the works fine in node v14 but not in node v16 . Any suggestions as to why this could be happening ?

```js
describe('when. reequest has xid headers', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    app = express();
    nock('http://localhost', {
      reqheaders: {
        xid: 'xid-test',
      },
    })
    .get('/').reply(200, {});
  });
  it('should have the cirrect header in the downstream call', (done)=> {
    app.get('/user', (req, res)=> {
      request = {};
      service.get({
        url: '/',
        name: 'fetch something',
        request
      }).then((value => {
        expect(value).toEqusl('test');
        done();
      }));
      supertest(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('xid', 'xid-test')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
      });
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I'd guess that something broke with the way `nock()` tries to steal `http.request()` or something changed in how `supertest()` makes its requests that isn't compatible with the hacks that nock is using.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @jfriend00 nock() is not a part of the problem. I have a set up without it (only supertest and express) and it also fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I was doing restructuring like

```
const newRequest = { 
  ..req,
 // my stuff
}
```

Check your code, maybe don't preserve original request as well.

Comment: Why is this an issue for 16 but not 14?